# trigger build for git repo B for a commit/pull request done on Git repo A using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My objective is to trigger a build on Git repo A whenever there is commit/Pull request done on Git Repo B. Git repo has all the pipeline code as separate groovy code and Git Repo b has the application Code done by dev team. I would like to test the case where a commit done in pipeline code is triggering the build in application code. How can I acheive this using Jenkins 2 with pipeline? Any thoughts or approach how it is done is greatly appreciated.

Here is my jenkinsfile in Git repo A.

```
branches {
    masterBranch = 'master'

}

integration {

pullRequest {
    version = gradle {    
        goals = 'clean build'
        gradlePath = '/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle'
    }

}

master {
    version = gradle {
        goals = 'clean build'
        gradlePath = '/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle'
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Did you check Jenkins shared Library pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create 2 jobs

- git repo a : with development code
- git repo b : with option "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" in
  build triggers job config.

then  use "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" to build required job( repo A ) based on the previous build status.

- ref :
  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: I had the jenkins pipeline job running for git Repo A and have another one configured foe Git Repo B. So both are pipeline jobs. But trying to figure how to trigger the build on B when A is complete.